# hugging face pipeline error from langchain PydanticUserError:

Tags: database, artificial-intelligence, langchain, large-language-model

I'm having following error while trying to load the hugging face pipeline from langchain

> PydanticUserError: If you use `@root_validator` with pre=False (the
> default) you MUST specify `skip_on_failure=True`. Note that
> `@root_validator` is deprecated and should be replaced with
> `@model_validator`.

I tried to following solution but the problem doesn't go away

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class HuggingFacePipeline(BaseModel):
    # Existing code...

    @validator("*", pre=True)
    def check_skip_on_failure(cls, value):
        return value

    # Existing code...
```